# How to interpret the results of a training/validation learning curve?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, variance

I am using the Random Forest classifier in the Scikit package and have plotted F1 scores versus training set size. The red is the training set F1 scores and the green is the scores for the validation set. This is about what I expected but I would like some advice on interpretation.

- I see that there is some significant variance, yet the validation curve *appears* to be converging. Should I assume that adding data would do little to affect the variance given the convergence or am I jumping to conclusion about the rate of convergence?
- Is the amount of variance here significant enough to warrant taking further actions that may increase the bias slightly? I realize this is a fairly domain-specific question but I wonder if there is any general guidelines for how much variance is worth a bit of bias tradeoff?

[image: Random Forest F1 score validation (Red = training, Green = validation)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see that there is some significant variance, yet the validation curve appears to be converging. Should I assume that adding data would do little to affect the variance given the convergence or am I jumping to conclusion about the rate of convergence?

This seems true conditioning on your learning procedure, thus in particular - selection of hyperparameters. Thus it does not mean that given different set of hyperparameters the same effect would occur. It only seems that given current setting - rate of convergence is relatively small thus getting to 95% would probably require significant amounts of data.

> Is the amount of variance here significant enough to warrant taking further actions that may increase the bias slightly? I realize this is a fairly domain-specific question but I wonder if there is any general guidelines for how much variance is worth a bit of bias tradeoff?

Yes, in general - these kind of curves at least do not reject option to go for higher bias. You clearly overfit towards training set. On the other hand, trees usually do that, thus increasing bias might be hard without changing the model. One option that I would suggest is going for [Extremely Randomized Trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html), which is nearly the same as Random Forest, but with randomly chosen threshold instead of full optimization. They have significantly bigger bias and should take these curves a bit closer to each other.

Obviously there is no guarantee - as you said, this is data specific, but the general characteristic looks promising (however might require changing the model).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response!